# Can PHP constants' values be changed per HTTP request?

Tags: php, constants

I'd like to know from a design POV whether changing the value of a constant per HTTP request is discouraged or perfectly ok.

I have a few constants that are defined at the start of a PHP script and they're used to figure out a particular context (what is the user trying to do at the time). The constants are never changed throughout the lifecycle of the script so they conform with the rules of constants and they work well. However, the values of these constants depends on what the user's doing. I'm wondering whether this is discouraged or perfectly acceptable in PHP.

```
<?php
// This function is only run once per HTTP request at the start
function new_paper() {
    define('NEW_PAPER', 1);
    define('NEW_VERSION', 0);
}

// This function is also only run once per HTTP request at the start
function new_paper_version() {
    define('NEW_PAPER', 0);
    define('NEW_VERSION', 1);
}

// This function is subsequently called by both functions above
function a_handler_of_sorts() {

    if (NEW_PAPER) {
        // Do something if it's a new paper
    }
    elseif (NEW_VERSION) {
        // Do something if it's a new version
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

In no circumstances are both `new_paper()` and `new_paper_version()` run in the same HTTP request.

Comment: Do you want to define the constant with different values?

Comment: Constant should be constant. If something changes - use variables - they are for this.

Comment: They are called `constant` for a reason.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam The constant is initialised with the value of 0 or 1 at the start of the script and then never changed, only checked. Which is why I'm so curious.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I'm not changing the value of the constants, only initialising them with different values.

Comment: @JoshBrown update question and  provide code how do you do it

Comment: Over the course of today I've thought about it and, to me, this seems like an acceptable usage of constants as they are still constant per http request, just initialises with different values depending on the context.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski just updated.

Comment: @kerbholz Constants are constant *during runtime*. PHP runtime is (typically) very short. Nothing says each runtime can't define its own constants.

Comment: Avoid using GLOBAL constans - instead create class which contains constans (and use it in static way). In your case instead constans, create class and set proper values to in in place e.g. where you distinct routing

Comment: I usually would use class constants, in this case I'm using a Drupal 7 site which is predominantly written in a procedural style so I'm keeping it consistent. I know that you couldn't replicate this functionality with an OOP site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical use case would be something like:

```
define('DEBUG', !empty($_GET['debug']));

if (DEBUG) echo 'some debugging statement';
```

<sub>Obviously don't do this *only* based on a query parameter, especially not in production, but you get the idea.</sub>

So, yes, setting constant values based on the request is fine. Whether this is the best thing to do in your particular case is questionable and I don't know. I'd really reserve it for "meta" values like debug flags, not for values which are essentially function parameters, inputs for your business logic. **Do this sparingly.**

"Constant values" which influence how every script works independently of the request would be something like config files or environment variables, e.g. containing database access credentials and such.

Comment: Thanks! I was curious because I thought, if the constants are just going to be uninitialised for each request and they're going to store an unchanged value, why not use them. But I appreciate the meta point, so I'll change them to vars. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you look at it from a unit testing perspective, you'll quickly discover when you should and shouldn't use constants. Try to write unit tests for your code, and suddenly discover that you can't test two cases in one run because you have defined something as constant that you need to change, so it should really have been a function parameter…

Answer (score 1):

Constants should **not** change during the request but as you said yours don't so I think you're OK there.

They represent fixed things such as how many DB connections are allowed, the name of the application etc. If you're trying to use them to store the state of your application then you could consider doing something like:

```
<?php
define('STATE_PAPER', 0);
define('STATE_VERSION', 1);
define('STATE_INVALID', 2);

$applicationState = null;

if (someCheckForPaper() === true) {
    $applicationState = NEW_PAPER;
} else if (someCheckForVersion() === true) {
    $applicationState = NEW_VERSION;
} else {
    $applicationState = STATE_INVALID;
}

// Save $applicationState somewhere... maybe session?

// Somewhere else
if ($applicationState === STATE_PAPER) {
    ...
}
```